# Declaring "this.object" in variable name "x" not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to call a function on input that prevents the user from typing more than two values but it doesn't work when I declare it in a variable.

This is my code:

```js
function maximum(object) {
    const maxlength = 2;
    let x = object.value;
    if (x.length > maxlength) {
        x = x.slice(0, maxlength);
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to work but doing this:

```html
<script>
  function maxLengthCheck(object) {
    if (object.value.length > object.max.length)
      object.value = object.value.slice(0, object.max.length)
  }
```

This is someone's else code from JSFiddle not mine and I don't quite understand why mine doesn't work and this does.

```html
<div class="row2">
         <br><input type="number" name="year" id="year" 
         placeholder="YY" oninput="maximum(this)">
</div>
```

```html
<input name="myInput_DRS"
    oninput="maxLengthCheck(this)"
    type = "number"
    placeholder="Type..."
    min = "1"
    max = "999" />
```

Comment: JS is pass by value, not pass by reference. Reassigning a variable doesn't "update" the original object that was assigned to the value.

Comment: You can’t declare `this.object` in variable name `x`. This is literally impossible to do. Because it doesn’t mean anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` is a **copy** of the value of the input.

`x` is **not** a *reference* to the value of the input.

Your function modifies `x`, but that is pointless because nothing ever subsequently reads `x`.

To modify `object.value` you have to modify `object.value`, not `x`.